# socket.io-stream facing 404 issue when accessing in socket client and server also

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, audio-streaming

I was trying to create an mp3 stream (already added the .mp3 file in my machine) using socket.io-stream and access it using the  client.html file.

After installing the **socket.io-stream** with npm and started, getting the below error in chrome console:

> http://localhost:5001/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ss is not defined

Here is my client.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bb</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js"></script>
    <h1>Audio Testing 1 2 3</h1>
    <audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
<br>


<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:' + window.location.port);
var audio = document.getElementById('audioSource');
console.log("hoi");
socket.on('start', function (data) {
  console.log("start");
  console.log(data);
  // socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  socket.emit('stream', { my: 'data' });
  console.log("");
  ss(socket).on('audio-stream', function(stream, data) {
    parts = [];
    console.log("DATA -->> ")
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk);
      parts.push(chunk);
    });
    stream.on('end', function () {
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
      audio.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(parts));
      audio.play();
    });
  });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my server.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/html`));

server.listen('5001');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index2.html');
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('start', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('stream', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var stream = ss.createStream();
    var filename = __dirname + '/audio/musicfile.mp3' ;
    ss(socket).emit('audio-stream', stream, { name: filename });
    fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
  });
});
```

Also please suggest any pointers (latest tutorials/articles related to socket audio streaming).

Comment: Quick question do you have the file socket.io-stream.js located in your public directory so it is accessible at the url: http://localhost:5001/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js ? does it work if you use "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io-stream/0.9.1/socket.io-stream.js" instead?

Comment: @Lagoni That worked(When using the cdnjs link.). Thanks. However, moving forward with the requirement, when I'm getting the mp3 file played in my windows machine when accessing the url: http://localhost:5001/ , why am I not able to play the file in mobile connected to 192.168.x.x:5001/ when both are in same LAN. I can see the html file loaded with audio controls, but unable to hit the play button. Any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is the `var socket = io('http://localhost:' + window.location.port);` it then tries to access the socket locally, on your phone. Which is not where your socket server is located :) I believe you can just say `var socket = io();` since your socket server is located on the same port as your express server.

Comment: Guess worked right. Now, able to get this working mobile as well. When I'm hitting the url in mobile, I was expecting the mp3 file to continue from a certain point of song length. I can use a method similar to audio.setPosition and then play, however, I'm trying a solution similar to icecast live streaming approach. Can we do this using sockets?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have any experience with either icecast or socket.io-stream, but i know that [createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) have an option called `start` and `end` where you can specify where to read from and to. Hope that can guide you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose the file to the public directory

```
$ cp node_modules/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js somewhere/public/
```

see: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream#browser